# jQuery Promise/Defered

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am using jQuery's getJSON method. Since it is asynchronous I am using the when method on the function that calls it to know when I can run my next function. The next function is to create a table using a handlebars template. I know the when is working because the template is created however I am not getting the data needed.

When using console.log I see the array attached to this but if I say this.objName it is undefined. So is the promise/deferred only saying that the request was successful? Is there a method that allows me to wait/watch for the data?

```
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        var TicketQueue = {
            init: function (config) {
                this.url = config.data;

                this.template = config.template;
                this.container = config.container;

                $.when(this.fetch()).done(this.attachTemplate());
            },
            attachTemplate: function () {
                var template = Handlebars.compile(this.template);

                this.container.append(template(this.tickets));

            },
            fetch: function () {
                var self = this;
                $.getJSON(this.url, function (data) {
                    self.tickets = $.map(data.tickets, function (ticket) {
                        return ticket;
                    });
                    //self.attachTemplate();
                });
            }
        };
        TicketQueue.init({
            template: $('#ticketQueueTpl').html(),
            container: $("table.ticketQueue"),
            data: "db/tickets.json"
        });
    }());
```

I have a comment self.attacheTemplate which does work but I am trying to make that function just the fetch and init initialize all of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) expects a Deferred as a parameter, otherwise it resolves straight away. Since you're not returning the AJAX promise from `this.fetch()`, the latter behaviour is been exhibited. **Return** the AJAX call from `this.fetch()`.

   ```
   fetch: function () {
       var self = this;
       return $.getJSON(this.url, function (data) {
           self.tickets = $.map(data.tickets, function (ticket) {
               return ticket;
           });
           //self.attachTemplate();
       });
   }
   ```
2. You're passing the *result* of `this.attachTemplate()` to `then()`, rather than the function itself. You want to be doing;

   ```
   $.when(this.fetch()).done(function () {
       this.attachTemplate()
   }.bind(this));
   ```

   Note I've stuck an extra `bind()` in there; that's because the value of `this` is lost in the anonymous function we're using.

---

Having said all of that, you don't even need `$.when()` in the first place; `$.when()` is good for *combining* multiple Deferreds into a single Deferred. Just use;

```
this.fetch().done(function () {
    this.attachTemplate();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: 1+ Congrats on the 1,000th answer.

Comment: @JoshC: Heh, I didn't realise myself. Drinks on me, I guess :P.

Comment: Thank you for all the clarification. Between javaScript and jQuery there is a lot to learn. I just want to try and get the good habits.

Comment: @Coury: I can completely relate... we've all been there :).